# Flutter: How to avoid automatic pluggin initialization on Flutter iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, plugins, appdelegate

I'm working with a plugin that I would like to manually register in iOS only if some condition is meet. Right now, the autogenerated **AppDelegate.swift** registers all plugins included in the **pubspect.yaml** with this line:

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
```

Is there any way to avoid registering a single plugin?

Thank you

Comment: I am having the similar issue. Have you found any workaround?

Comment: I have same question but for 3rd part plugin. I don't want it to be initialize till I call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way (after browsing and reading Flutter iOS engine documentation).

- write your plugin in Swift (this language is easier to understand. I am bad in objC ;) )
- have `AppDelegate.swift` (in Swift language too)
- create plugin in `AppDelegate.swift` (below `AppDelegate` class). This if for simplicity. In my case it is:

```swift
public class FlutterNativeTimezonePlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
    
    public static func addManuallyToRegistry(registry: FlutterPluginRegistry) {
        // https://api.flutter.dev/objcdoc/Protocols/FlutterPluginRegistry.html#/c:objc(pl)FlutterPluginRegistry(im)registrarForPlugin:
        let registrar = registry.registrar(forPlugin: "flutter_native_timezone")
        if let safeRegistrar = registrar {
            register(with: safeRegistrar)
        }
        
    }
    
    // this is an override of this fucnion:
    // https://api.flutter.dev/objcdoc/Protocols/FlutterPlugin.html#/c:objc(pl)FlutterPlugin(cm)registerWithRegistrar:
    public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "flutter_native_timezone", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
        let instance = FlutterNativeTimezonePlugin()
        registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
    }

  public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
    switch call.method {
    case "getLocalTimezone":
      result(NSTimeZone.local.identifier)
    case "getAvailableTimezones":
      result(NSTimeZone.knownTimeZoneNames)
    default:
      result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
    }
  }
}
```

- below `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)` method add the plugin initialisation one: `FlutterNativeTimezonePlugin.addManuallyToRegistry(registry: self)`

So this is manual way of adding a plugin for the iOS build. Shame there is no documentation.